# Doctrine entities have wrong ID after persist

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to insert an entity into SQL Server database

```
class Entity
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'ID')]
    private ?int $id = null;
}
```

In profiler, I can clearly see issued INSERT query. In database, there is a new record, with ID let's say 13287. But Doctrine assumes some random (low) ID for the entity, for example 4, 45, 50, ... Those ID's don't even exist in the DB. It then issues UPDATE etc. queries with said incorrect ID.

When I do manual insert:

```
INSERT ...
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Returned ID is correct. How does Doctrine compute entity ID? How can I force Doctrine to use ID actually inserted into DB?

Comment: It is because of triggers (on insert). When table has a trigger, it ruins last inserted ID query. How to solve it I do not know.